# How to tranform clang .ast file to ir or bitcode file?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

Apologize for my poor English.

```sh
[root@xxxx] ~
❯ clang -emit-ast aa.c

[root@xxxx] ~
❯ xxd aa.ast | head
00000000: 4350 4348 0108 0000 ce0a 0000 07c1 b3d0  CPCH............
00000010: 8cc2 2bb8 022d c8c2 2bb0 c22f 8802 2bbc  ..+..-..+../..+.
00000020: c228 acc2 4312 b442 29d0 4228 9042 28d0  .(..C..B).B(.B(.
00000030: 4228 3c30 472b bc02 29d4 022b 94c2 2fb8  B(<0G+..)..+../.
```

- I can get clang ast file with -emit-ast option
- and I want to transform it to llvm ir.
- But I cannot find any interface to solved it.

Anyone has suggests??

Answer (score 1):

Clang AST files can be used in place of source files, so the following code works:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```sh
> clang++ -emit-ast main.cpp -o a.ast
> clang++ a.ast -o a.out
> ./a.out
Hello, world!
```

Answering your question:

```sh
> clang -emit-llvm -c aa.ast
```